# agregar un script jquery usando javascript puro

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de ejecutar el siguiente código desde **php:**

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    var executefunction = "'."
        $.jAlert({
            'title': 'Alerta de Mesa de Control ',
            'content': '".$why."',
            'theme': 'green',
            'btns': { 
                'text': 'Cerrar',
                'onClick' : function(){
                    window.WWC(id,name);
                    window.location.reload(true);
                }
            },
            'onClose': function(){
                window.WWC(id,name);
                window.location.reload(true);
            },
        });';
    script.innerHTML = executefunction;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    </script>".'"';
```

la idea principal era que una vez el código **javascript** entre al **html**, tome el código **jquery** y lo pegue en el `body` al final.

pero me sale error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token por el $.jAlert.
```

**Actualizacion**

Intentando declararlo como función y almacenarlo como `string`:

```
<script>
                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) { 
                    var script = document.createElement('script');
                    var executefunction =  new function (".'"'."$.jAlert({'title': 'Alerta de Mesa de Control ','content': '" . $why . "','theme': 'green','btns': {'text': 'Cerrar','onClick' : function(){window.WWC(id,name);window.location.reload(true);}},'onClose': function(){window.WWC(id,name);window.location.reload(true);},})".'"'.");
                    script.innerHTML = executefunction();
                    document.body.appendChild(script);
                });
            </script>
```

**Quedo de la siguiente manera:**

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                        $.jAlert({
                                'title': 'Alerta del Sistema',
                                'class': 'usertimer',
                                'content': '".$why."',
                                'theme': 'red',
                                'closeBtn': true
                            });
            </script>";
```

Comment: tienes referenciado el archivo JS de $.jAlert? porque recuerda que es PHP pero tratara de buscar las librerias y si no las encuentra por eso te muestra ese error.

Comment: si, funciona correctamente, el problema es que este echo suele aparecer fuera del html. es por ese motivo que uso javascript puro, de tal manera que el jquery sea agregado primero y luego ejecutado. pero como que no me funciona, acabo de agregar una actualizacion.

Comment: Deberias colocar el HTML

Comment: probaste lo que te actualice en la respuesta?

Comment: El problema son las comillas que estás usando: en PHP estás usando dobles y escapando la cadena con simples, pero luego dentro de la cadena también estás usando simples (en el JSON), lo que va a hacer que se rompa la cadena en JavaScript y recibas ese error.

Comment: Además, habría que ver el contenido de `$why` porque si contiene unas comillas puede romper la cadena también-

Comment: ese es el error que le quite en mi respuesta , porque note eso mismo que tenia muchos escapes que no hacia, pero no se si lo habrá probado

Answer (score -1, accepted):

tienes una concatenacion extrana luego de declarar `var executefunction = **"'."**`, lo que te tra consigo que al final tengas que hacer lo mismo y alomejor por eso, te da ese error escapa una sola comilla `'` , o las de dos `"` , en una sola sentencia, te quedaria asi:

```
echo "<script>
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      var executefunction =  $.jAlert({

        'title': 'Alerta de Mesa de Control ',
        'content': '".$why."',
        'theme': 'green',
        'btns': { 
            'text': 'Cerrar',
            onClick : function(){
                window.WWC(id,name);
                window.location.reload(true);
            }
        },
        onClose: function(){
            window.WWC(id,name);
            window.location.reload(true);
        },
    });
    script.innerHTML = executefunction;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
</script>";
```

Comment: sigue saliendo Unexpected token  en var executefunction =  $.jAlert({

Comment: mira ver ahora , que me fije los `onClick` y `onClose` tenian unas comillas de mas y un **';** de mas, sustituye el código por este ahora